# Golang PutItem DynamoDB: Runtime Error invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

New to programming with golang and AWS.
    Block of code in my function, trying out creating a new table and writing 
    values to it using AWS DynamoDB. 
    Creation is successful, but the program crashes when the Write happens. 
    Not sure why..I'd be really grateful if anyone could help me out!

```
**Logs**:

2015/07/22 15:46:46 TableStatus: 0xc208193cb0
2015/07/22 15:46:46 End
2015/07/22 15:46:48 Sleep 2: Before Write
2015/07/22 15:46:48 Before Defining Input
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x401b28]

**Code Block:**
 {
    log.Println("Entry+++")
        cfg := aws.DefaultConfig

        svc := dynamodb.New(cfg)

        tableDefinition := &dynamodb.CreateTableInput{
            TableName:            aws.String("table1"),
            AttributeDefinitions: make([]*dynamodb.AttributeDefinition, 1, 1),
            KeySchema:            make([]*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement, 1, 1),
            ProvisionedThroughput: &dynamodb.ProvisionedThroughput{
                ReadCapacityUnits:  aws.Long(1),
                WriteCapacityUnits: aws.Long(1),
            },
        }

        tableDefinition.KeySchema[0] = &dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{
            AttributeName: aws.String("batch_id"),
            KeyType:       aws.String("HASH"),
        }
        tableDefinition.AttributeDefinitions[0] = &dynamodb.AttributeDefinition{
            AttributeName: aws.String("batch_id"),
            AttributeType: aws.String("S"),
        }

        resp, err := svc.CreateTable(tableDefinition)
        log.Println("After CreateTable---")

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("create table failed", err.Error())
            return
        }
        if resp != nil && resp.TableDescription != nil {
            log.Println(
                "TableStatus:", resp.TableDescription.TableStatus)
        }

        log.Println("End")
        //Some time before the createTable transaction gets committed. 
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        log.Println("Sleep 2 Before Write")

        testA := "batch_1" //value to be written to the db
        // testB := "batch_name"
        // testC := "530"
        // testD := "Sample-Keyy-98"

        log.Println("Before Defining Input")
        input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
            TableName: aws.String("table1"),
            Item: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                "batch_id": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    S: aws.String(testA),
                },
                // "name": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                //  S: aws.String(testB),
                // },
            },
        }

        _, err2 := svc.PutItem(input)
    }
```

Comment: Please post a bit more of the stack trace, it'll actually show you the line where the error occurred.

Comment: Yes, we need the location of the panic from the stack trace, and where that is in your code. This doesn't look like a usual nil-pointer dereference, bc the panic addr is 0x20.

Comment: Without knowing the line number at which code is panicking, It is very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, I apologize for the delay, it crashes right after input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput. But after going through some more pages on the web on dynamoDB, got the program to write successfully to dynamo. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It would be very helpful if you could show the stack trace of error. But until then i could say that this error usually occurs when you try to access member of any uninitialized variable.
For example if this error is comming at following line

```
a := b.c
```

then you need to check if b is initialized properly. Most probably value of b is nil hence nil pointer dereference.

Answer (score 1):

```
Following is what I could come up with from whatever I read across the net.
Working on local secondary indexes, range index and timestamps presently.
Thanks again!    


    package main

    import (
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        // "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awsutil"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"

        "log"
        "strconv"
        "time"
    )

    type dynamo struct {
        db            *dynamodb.DynamoDB
        tableName     string
        readCapacity  int64
        writeCapacity int64
    }

    type metadata struct {
        dynamoDb  *dynamo
        batchID   string
        field1    string
        field2    string
        batchSize int //In Bytes
    }

    func newDynamo(name string, readCapacity, writeCapacity int64) *dynamo {
        cfg := aws.DefaultConfig
        return &dynamo{
            db:            dynamodb.New(cfg),
            tableName:     name,
            readCapacity:  readCapacity,
            writeCapacity: writeCapacity,
        }
    }

    func newMetadata(batchID, field1Val, field2Val string, batchSizeVal int) *metadata {
        return &metadata{
            batchID:   batchID,
            field1:    field1Val,
            field2:    field2Val,
            batchSize: batchSizeVal,
        }
    }

    var dynDB *dynamo
    var m *metadata

    func main() { //create the *metadata struct object, and it can then call writeToDynamo fn
        log.Println("Entry")

        dynDB = newDynamo("tableName", 1, 1) //make a new dynamo struct object
        dynDB.createTable()

        m = newMetadata("field1Value", "field2Value", 232)
        m.setDynamoDB()

        m.writeToDynamo()

        log.Println("Exit")
    }

    func (d *dynamo) createTable() (err error) {
        log.Println("createTable Entry")
        tableDefinition := &dynamodb.CreateTableInput{
            TableName: aws.String(d.tableName),
            AttributeDefinitions: []*dynamodb.AttributeDefinition{ // Required
                { // Required
                    AttributeName: aws.String("batchID"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("S"), // Required
                },
            },
            KeySchema: []*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{ // Required
                { // Required
                    AttributeName: aws.String("batchID"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("HASH"), // Required
                },
            },
            ProvisionedThroughput: &dynamodb.ProvisionedThroughput{
                ReadCapacityUnits:  aws.Long(d.readCapacity),
                WriteCapacityUnits: aws.Long(d.writeCapacity),
            },
        }

        resp, err := dynDB.db.CreateTable(tableDefinition)
        log.Println("After CreateTable---")

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("create table failed", err.Error())
            return err
        }
        if resp != nil && resp.TableDescription != nil {
            log.Println("TableStatus:", resp.TableDescription.TableStatus)
        }

        log.Println("CreateTable Exit")

        //Sleep for 15 seconds, this is better when put in a function that validates the table that was created,
        //But for testing, the program is put to sleep for 15 seconds. Program may fail if writeToDynamo is exedcuted
        //without the table being in ACTIVE state.
        time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
        return
    }

    func (m *metadata) writeToDynamo() {
        log.Println("writeToDynamo")

        //Not exactly able to figure out what was wrong with the prev code snippet
        params := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
            TableName: aws.String(m.dynamoDb.tableName),
            Item: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                "batchID": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    S: aws.String(m.batchID),
                },
                "field2": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    S: aws.String(m.field2),
                },
                "field3": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    S: aws.String(m.field3),
                },
                "batchSize": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    N: aws.String(strconv.Itoa(m.batchSize_Compressed)),
                },
            },
        }

        resp2, err2 := dynDB.db.PutItem(params)

        if err2 != nil {
            // if awsErr, ok := err2.(awserr.Error); ok { // Generic AWS error with Code, Message, and original error (if any)
            //  log.Println(awsErr.Code(), awsErr.Message(), awsErr.OrigErr())
            //  if reqErr, ok := err.(awserr.RequestFailure); ok {
            //      // A service error occurred
            //      log.Println(reqErr.Code(), reqErr.Message(), reqErr.StatusCode(), reqErr.RequestID())
            //  }
            // } else { // This case should never be hit, the SDK should always return an //
            //  //error which satisfies the awserr.Error interface.
            //  log.Println(err2.Error())
            // }
            log.Println("Error while Writing:", err2.Error())
        }
        log.Println("Response:", awsutil.StringValue(resp2))
    }

    func (m *metadata) setDynamoDB() {
        m.dynamoDb = dynDB
    }
```